# 16MHz Crystal trace length

Tags: pcb

I can't length match the traces from my microcontroller to its 16MHz crystal. The trace length difference is quite different, as you can see. Would this be a problem?

[image: crystal]

Comment: who said they had to be matched? Matching is for a 4 port controlled impedance. Not a crystal. One side is low impedance from output, the other high impedance. THey just need to be guarded with a ground perimeter and within a few mm of pads.

Comment: Is this an XO? I dont see the load caps

Comment: Thank you for the input. And sorry for the late response. Yes it is a TXC 7B series XO. I won't match it as this is XO!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a crystal connected to the internal oscillator of an IC, like you have, you don't need to match the track lengths. Keep the tracks as short as possible and keep the tracks on one layer over a ground plane if possible.

The latter reduces interference into the oscillator circuit and reduces the interference from the oscillator onto other circuitry.

What you have looks good.

Comment: Abracon's use caps , dont they?

Comment: Either end of the 4-pin crystal on his board.

Comment: If he knew how to create 24~30pF pad caps yet not know the XTal PI filter is a low pass+ BP filter and yet wanted to match <1cm lengths, I am surprised. the problem is lack of awareness of how an XO works. and how much test pads can interfere with crosstalk jitter, if phase noise matters at all. ( e.g. SDR) The main thing is **the traces are unbalanced impedances, so you never  balance track lengths in this scenario, as the timing skew is intentional with the series R , shunt Cap LPF differential delay vs gnd**

Comment: one side of XTAL is high impedance sine wave and other is low Z square wave!

Comment: @TonyStewartEESince75, why surprised? OP went as far as they knew how, copying the ds/appnote with xtal and caps. Showed resourcefulness then asked a fair question on a helping forum. If they knew the answer, they wouldn't have asked. We all did the same, c'mon, you must have wanted someone to help you back in 1975 :-) And it's Christmas.

Comment: good point. I read every design app and Mil-Std-Hdbk on Xtals's before I designed an XO, others still need to learn do this. so my questions were different, like how to reduce phase noise to -140dB/Hz and I was lucky to work with good mentors and read Jim WIlliams reports.  Merry Xmas.  I was stuck in finding someone to help on an allpass 75 Ohm filter 3 band splitting mux filter on coax though for weeks.

Comment: Although I remember hiring a grad in 1999 when I worked in San Diego, who could not answer the interview question. What is a crystal?  He could program with autoscript ok though.

Comment: @TonyStewartEESince75, thanks and there are plenty about. I too have little patience for skivers or people pasting homework questions but much time for those trying to understand and get further. But this site has not shortage of contributors, many regulars, who write sneering and mocking comments, sometimes just five words of ridicule. To me, they disgrace engineering. Good engineers and people running a real factory taught a young apprentice-me - they saw it as handing on knowledge that didn't belong to them anyway, so that I could do the same for others later. That's an admirable stance :-)